# longest flowpath from a subbasin file and DEM/Flow direction? Not being able to do in Archydro?

Tags: python, r, arcgis, qgis

Need to make a shapefile of longest  flowpath from a subbasin file and DEM/Flow direction? Not being able to do in Archydro?

Tried Archydro and Hecgeohms, the code seemed like it would run but it crashed and whenever it did , the results were very small compared not even touching subbasin boundary?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.